# Configure CloudFlare to point to Fortrabbit

Tags: configuration, dns, cloudflare, domain-name, fortrabbit

I am trying to configure CloudFlare allowing users access web app via http:// and http://www.

Here is CloudFlare DNS records as currently stand:

```
CNAME mapio.co.uk   is an alias of mapio.eu1.frbit.net  Automatic
CNAME www   is an alias of mapio.co.uk  Automatic
```

App is hosted by Fortrabbit and working fine when accessed via http://mapio.co.uk/ , but unfortunately http://www.mapio.co.uk/ will bring following message:

```
It nearly works
The App is not set up yet. Please wait a little longer.
The App has been deleted or disabled.
This is not the correct address. Please check for typos.
Something else. Please check the fortrabbit status.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with fortrabbit, but make sure that you have your "Custom Domains" or "Host Name" setup for both your main site and your www site.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @snuggy. The domain name purchased with [godaddy](https://uk.godaddy.com/) and Nameservers  customised as per CloudFlare instructions.

Fortrabbit domains recommend using routing as CNAME desired mapio.eu1.frbit.net which has been set on CloudFlare.

However in the Fortrabbit dashboard having following message:

`No A or CNAME record found. Your domain is most likely not configured correctly. See our help for more infos.`

Comment: @Alexanderp I just went through the signup process and looks like you need to add each domain separately. One for the naked domain, and one for the www domain.
So you should get to this page twice (http://imgur.com/ATHhApN)

Comment: apologies for the delay and many thanks for your response!!! All works perfectly now. Thank you for your answer!